# How can I load crystal reports in web viewer without credentials?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

Hello we have an in house vb.net based application that will allow users to load and access reports that we have generated on a file server. When they are created they are made in the visual studio designer using an ODBC connection. We have decided to port this application over to a web based system using asp.net but have ran into a snag.  The viewer on the web page will load the reports (we can verify this by date criteria that appears on some) but a login page will appear that ask us for the following fields; Server Name, Database name, User name, and password. The top field being the server name is incorrect in that its not a valid hostname, unfortunately it will not let us change it. I have tried various in-code methods to override this message. I have set the credentials in the code, disabled the login in code, I even copied the exact ODBC connection settings to the server the site runs on. Has anyone ever had an issue with crystal reports viewer like this?

Some of the code I use to attempt to resolve this was to create the credentials and set them for each table like so.

```
  For Each CrTable In CrTables
        crTableLogonInfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo
        crTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo =
        ConnInfo
        CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogonInfo)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the parameters into your web config as a key as follow:

```
<add key="ServerName" value="Your Server"/>
<add key="DataBaseName" value="Your DB Name"/>
<add key="DatabaseUser" value="DB User"/>
<add key="DatabasePassword" value="DB Password"/>
```

Second, In your report viewer file, at bind report method add this code:

```
    Dim SERVER_NAME As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ServerName").ToString()
    Dim DATABASE_NAME As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DataBaseName").ToString()
    Dim DatabaseUser As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DatabaseUser").ToString()
    Dim DatabasePassword As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DatabasePassword").ToString()
```

Finally add this code:

```
rptobj.SetDatabaseLogon(DatabaseUser, DatabasePassword, SERVER_NAME, DATABASE_NAME)
```

***some developers find this approach unsecured because you are showing the DB credentials you can encrypt it and then decrypt it for security issues.**